# Laravel Presenters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm curious to know if I need the `null` at the end of the presenter return statement since `old()` will return null if a value isn't found.

**Event Form**

```
<input type="date" data-plugin="datetimepicker" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="{{ old('date') ?? $event->formatted_form_date }}"/>
```

**Presenter**

```
public function formattedFormDate()
{
    return $this->model->date ? $this->model->date->format('m/d/Y') : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `value="{{ old('date') ?? $event->formatted_form_date }}"` means If `old('date')` has a value, return that value else return `$event->formatted_form_date`.

Returning `null` from `formattedFormDate()` depends on the `date` attribute on the `model`. If its `nullable`, then it means there may be instances where `$this->model->date` would return `null` and hence the need for the return `null` else if its not `nullable` it is always guaranteed that the `$this->model->date` would never be `null` which makes the return `null` from the `formattedFormDate()` useless.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So everything is fine as is?

Comment: wait, in the form view, do you have an `$event` variable?

Comment: Yes. This is out of a form partial where obviously if an event is being created then the date form field would be null until the user adds in the date but if the edit page is loaded then there would always be a date.

Comment: oh ok... is the `date` `nullable` in your database?

Comment: No its not nullable in my database.

Comment: Then i think you dont need the `null` since `$this->model->date` will always return a `date`

Comment: You can just return `$this->model->date->format('m/d/Y')` from the function directly.